# how pass data between view controller and TableViewController when using dismiss page that opened with performSegue in swift 4?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, swift4

I used this code here to pass data from first view controller to the second view controller

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? secondViewController {
        vc.showPageType = self.checkEdit
   }
```

But the problem is that in the second view controller I have text field that when user fill that text field and push the button submit the secondViewController will be dismiss with this method

```
dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

and now I can't use perform segue method to pass textfield text to the first view controller how can I do that in swift4?

Comment: Use delegates to pass data from B->A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data to another controller on dismiss ViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706662/how-to-pass-data-to-another-controller-on-dismiss-viewcontroller)

Comment: there is a problem my firstviewcontroller is a tableviewcontroller not view controller

Comment: That's not a problem ,  tableviewcontroller is a sub class of UIViewController.

Comment: ok so in that question where should I write protocol in the view controller or table view controller ?

Comment: please refer the link.Or read this -: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.htmlhttps://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: this link won't be exist can you write codes here please ? and I will give you vote because I used similar question But It doesn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your secondViewController source code file:

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate {

    func submitButtonPushedWithText(_ text: String)
}
```

Add to class secondViewController property:

```
var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?
```

Then conform your first controller to SecondViewControllerDelegate and implement method submitButtonPushedWithText(:):

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SecondViewControllerDelegate {

    func submitButtonPushedWithText(_ text: String) {
        // use text from textField of second controller 
    }
}
```

Also setup delegate property of second controller before presenting:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let vc = segue.destination as? secondViewController {
    vc.showPageType = self.checkEdit
    // setup delegate
    vc.delegate = self
}
```

Now you can call method submitButtonPushedWithText(_ text: String) in your Second controller just before calling dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil):

```
func submitButtonPushed() {
    delegate?.submitButtonPushedWithText(textField.text!)
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```