# how to use segue after using webview?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

how do i perform segue when i exit the webview? it keeps throwing the sigbart error

```swift
class Sample: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate{
    var url = String()
    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myURL = URL(string:"\(url)")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.load(myRequest)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMain", sender: self)
        }
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        webView.stopLoading()
    }   
}
```

Comment: var url = String() has a data passed on by the previous view

Comment: You should change line 3 to `@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView?` and replace all references to `webView` with `webView?` to avoid segmentation faults

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't have to do to with the webview if it is crashing on the segue. If you are trying to push to a new controller make sure you have your identifier set like below:

[image]

If you are just trying to go back one controller you can use:

`self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

instead of:

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMain", sender: self)`

If you need to go back multiple views look into unwindToSegue functionality.

I would also consider moving the stopLoading function to `viewWillDisappear` since it has nothing to do with the segue itself.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.webView.stopLoading()
}
```

Comment: the dismiss worked but i would like to go to a different view instead of the previous one. But when using segue i keep on getting the sigbart error. the segue works on different views but when im trying to exit the webview it keeps throwing the sigbart error. also ive doubled check the identifier and its completely the same as my code

Comment: Is the viewcontroller that you are attempting to go to already in the stack?

Comment: Yup. the dismiss func works but i need to pass data so i need to use segue. Also i dont have any buttons. It should go back automatically to the Main module when the conditions are met.

Comment: Sorry this seems out of the scope of the original question now. If you would like information on how to pass data on dismiss try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43706791/12555191